# error al ejecutar comando 'dir' en servidor ftp

Tags: windows, ftp, ascii

Tengo un problema cuando ejecuto  el comando *dir* o *ls* en un servidor ftp, anexo la imagen del error. Otros comandos como *pwd* o *cd* si me funcionan.
agradecería su ayuda.
[image: error al ejecutar el comando dir]

Answer (score 1):

Como puedes leer en el siguiente enlace [FTP command channel and data channel](https://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/80512/active-v-s-passive-ftp-simplified), FTP usa dos canales para comunicación. En un resumen:

- **Command channel**: Canal para el envío de comandos.
- **Data channel**: Canal para la transferencia de datos o respuesta de comandos.

Puedes establecer bien la conexión y lanzar comandos que no requieran que te devuelvan información ya que van por el canal de comandos. Pero a la hora de que se necesite usar el canal de datos, como es en el caso del comando `dir` para devolverte resultados, se está cerrando la conexión. Puede que se te esté bloqueando la conexión al momento de recibir los datos por el firewall de Windows o incluso el mismo router.

Puedes mirar también [modo pasivo y activo FTP](https://ccnadesdecero.es/diferencias-ftp-modo-activo-pasivo/). Como ves en la entrada, el modo activo el cliente inicia una conexión para enviar comandos y le indica un puerto al servidor para recibir los datos. Luego el servidor intenta comunicar los datos e inicia otra conexión. En cambio en el modo pasivo siempre es el cliente quien inicia la conexión. Tanto para lanzar comandos como para recibir datos. Intenta usando el modo pasivo y revisa si existe la posibilidad de que algún firewall esté prohibiendo la conexión.

Ten en cuenta que hay clientes que no permiten el uso del modo pasivo (lo digo porque estás en windows). Puedes intentar con WinSCP.